# GoDaddy VPS running Magento went down twice past couple of weeks

Tags: php, centos, magento

Would this PHP error possibly cause the server to go down?

> [Tue Mar 05 02:48:28 2013] [error] [client 50.57.68.9] PHP Fatal
>   error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File
>   'httpdocs/media/catalog/product/cache/1/' does not exists.' in
>   httpdocs/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 httpdocs/get.php(205):
>   Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/var/www/vhosts...')\n#1
>   httpdocs/get.php(165): sendFile('/var/www/vhosts...')\n#2 {main}\n
>   thrown in lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why I was down voted. If someone explained along with the down vote that's more helpful than not saying anything. So then I don't do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Absent any other relevant information: No.

An uncaught exception in PHP should not cause your web server to "go down".
It will however make your PHP application bail out when it encounters the exception, which could have a variety of symptoms (blank page, page of error messages, etc.) that may be reported to you as ["THE WEBSITE IS DOWN!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8_Kfjo3VjU)

Comment: Have a big +1 for http://www.thewebsiteisdown.com/.

Comment: I didn't think it would cause the website to go down either. The website was for sure down I couldn't get to plesk either. It was displaying this page isn't available. I'll have to check the system logs would that be better?